# Check Convergence of $\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*(\frac{e^n}{n!})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n*(\frac{e^n}{n!})$$
what I decided to do is to use Delambre test, what I get is:
$$\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}*\frac{n!}{e^n} = \frac{e}{n+1}$$
1) the limit is $n\rightarrow \infty =0$

2) monotonically decreasing

the answer is absolute convergence, what I did wrong in my way to show it.
I know that the limit is only prerequisite but not enough, how I need to show it with another way?
thanks!

Comment: note that your second equation should be $e^{n+1}$ not $e^n + 1$? you'd need to use $\{n+1 \}$

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{e^n}{n!}=e^{-e}$$

Comment: Yes, I see it now, thanks I fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us put

$$a_n:=\frac{e^n}{n!}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{e^n}=\frac e{n+1}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}0$$

Thus, the series converges absolutely and thus it also converges, i.e.:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^n}{n!}\;\;\text{converges} \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{e^n}{n!}\;\;\text{also converges}$$